# How to use both "my own internet connection" and "remote lan vpn connection"?

Tags: vpn, internet, port-forwarding

I have service in a remote LAN, and i could have VPN connection to there over my regular internet connection (i have white IP, normally visible).

Now i want to expose some service from that remote lan to the internet. But the problem is that when i connect VPN i cannot use my "regular" connection. Every software piece starts thinking that i am acting from that remote LAN, even browser start showing totally wrong external IP (not my white IP).

So i cannot launch web server and expose data from remote lan, accessible through VPN.

Could i use VPN and the regular internet port as the same time? (I guess i can, via additional machine or virtual machine and port forwarding, but is there more straightforward way?)

PS. WinServer 2016

PPS. In other words, i want that LAN requests 10.*** go through VPN, but everything other would work as it normally do. How to set this up?

Comment: What OS is the client running (I presume Win Server 2016 is the server?) This is likely primarily about routing, so please include the client's current routing table in your question.

Comment: @Attie no WinServer is a client, and i dont know/care what does run server. It just allows me to connect to my work lan, and my home pc runs winserver for some unrelated reasons. When i try to edit routing table here with "route delete/add" i almost always end up totally loosing connectivity, and is forced to reboot machine.

Comment: @Attie In a home network i got `192.168...` ip. But when i connect from home to VPN at work i got an ip `10.0...` and everything starts go through it. Even my web browser starts to show me external IP at my work!!! BUT What i want is to remain everything as it was, except that only traffic addressed to`10.*.*.*` must go through VPN. I dont want to redirect all my traffic via VPN, but only need to access to some machines on that remote LAN. I want to save my OLD external internet IP so that web browser act like i was not connected there